# How to track dynamically-added elements using clickTale

Tags: javascript, jquery, analytics

I have a page http://www.supositorio.com/rcalc/rcalclite.htm which I am trying to track using clickTale the problem is that some of its elements are hidden by default and shown after the user clicks on some element. Is there a way to show the interaction with the hidden element?